# What is required to verify a zk-SNARK?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I am trying to verify a zk-SNARK from a solidity contract offline, in Rust.

This is the verifying contract that checks the proof in the [solidity side](https://etherscan.io/address/0xce172ce1f20ec0b3728c9965470eaf994a03557a#code#L1).

And [this](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0c79667f8de558a478da20ceb2777a0a17f5ce2e0941f5a05f604b0a6f20bbcf) is the transaction that carries the proof and the public inputs.

The proof is valid and I have been able to replicate the validation offline using Solidity.
However, in Rust I don't have access to the solidity precompile that checks BN254 pairings. So I am using this implementation based in arkworks/curve crate:

```
pub fn check_pairings(g1s: Vec<G1Affine>, g2s: Vec<G2Affine>) -> bool {
    assert_eq!(g1s.len(), g2s.len());
    let mut res = Fp12::one();
    for (g1, g2) in g1s.iter().zip(g2s.iter()) {
        if g1.is_zero() || g2.is_zero() {
            continue;
        }
        res = res * Bn254::pairing(*g1, *g2);
    }
    res.is_one()
}
```

The code is based in the [Ethereum BN526 implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/crypto/bn256/cloudflare/bn256.go#L322) and please note that:

- The inputs (vector of G1 and G2 points) are equivalent to the solidity implementation. So I can be sure the combination of inputs, loading of proof etc. is correct.
- It's basically the algorithm described in the original [Groth16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) paper, page 18. The A point component has been negated so that all the terms are in the same side of the equation.
- It's the same curve in both implementations.

Am I missing something? Is there some additional practical step when verifying a zk-SNARK? Is a normalization of values required?

Comment: Do you mean that your rust code doesn't validate the proof correctly?

Comment: @meshcollider Yes, my code does not validate the proof correctly.